# How to retrieve file names from a specific directory using JavaScript or jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, svg

I want to make a code using only JavaScript or/and jQuery to access a static directory and retrieve the names of some icons i saved there (SVG icons) and display the names to the user. i couldn't do that with the file api and i have no idea where to start.

Comment: You could make a server side page that scans and lists the contents of the folder.. Then You could use the client side to access it easily

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to assume from your mention of jQuery and the File API that you're trying to do this within a browser.

You can't. It just isn't allowed, there is no mechanism to provide it.

If you're in control of the machine where you want this information to be accessed, you can run a server process on it that can do that; code in the browser can then make a request to the server code to request the information. But there's no browser-only way to do it.